# Dplyr Syntax Without Repeating the Data Frame

Tags: r, dplyr

In *dplyr*, you can imply the data frame and pass it down to subsequent functions like so:

```
df <- df %>% select(one_of(c("Species", "Genus"))) %>% 
mutate(newcol = sum(length+width)
```

Is there a way in the syntax to make it so that I don't have to repeat the `df` on the right side of the arrow?

Answer (score 7):

It is not available in `dplyr` but is in `magrittr` library.

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

df %<>% ...
```

The `%<>%` operator says "pass to the functions on the right and than save to the object with the same name". For example:

```
mtcars %<>% mutate(cyl_plus_gear = cyl + gear) %>% arrange(cyl_plus_gear)
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks; I also found that this can be done by simply passing in the data frame as the first argument to the first function call in deployer.

Ex:

```
  df <- select(df,1:10)%>%filter(value > 10)
```

Comment: Yes, because what `%>%` does is it passes the left hand side object as first argument to the function on the right side.